# JQuery UI slider is not showing up, console shows error massage

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I'm trying to use JQuery UI slider in on of my carousel's items.
I attached JQuery UI files (css and js) and it's not showing up.

```
$("#slider").slider();

<div id="slider"></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

the link and script are at the bottom of my body tag. tried to move them to head and still not working. 
The console shows:

jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).slider is not a function TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function

head tag:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.6.2/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>-->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="jScripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!--<link href="Style/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.6.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css" />-->

<link href="styles/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define jquery-UI first.

When you calling **$("#slider").slider();**

**'.slider()'** function is not exist yet

Try to include jquery-UI library first.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>

$("#slider").slider();
```

Comment: that makes sense but it still doesn't show.... and the error still appears

Comment: Have you tried to put ``<div id="slider"></div>`` above ``$("#slider").slider();``?

``<div id="slider"></div> $("#slider").slider();``

Comment: theyre in 2 different files.... the div tag is in the html file and the jquery is in js file. I updated my question with my head tag references .. maybe u can see something...

Comment: ``$("#slider").slider();`` is calling when ``<div id="slider"></div>`` is not render yet.
Try to put ``<script src="jScripts/JavaScript.js"></script>`` to footer.

Comment: still not showing :( I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my head tag scripts and link.. did u see something wrong there?

Comment: I think it has to do with jquery slim version. The problem is my carousel isn't working if I don;t use the slim version./..

Comment: I see. I tried to use jquery instead of jquery-slim. Everything fine. It's seem caused by jquery-slim.

Comment: From the https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/

Slim build 

Sometimes you don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many standalone libraries that focus on ajax requests. **And often it is simpler to use a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all your web animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the ajax and effects modules, we’ve released a “slim” version that excludes these modules. All in all, it excludes ajax, effects, and currently deprecated code.**